# Check null value in variable in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this div

```
<td><a *ngIf="data?.URL; else noData"  [href]="data?.URL" target="_blank">View
                            File</a>
                            <ng-template #noData>
                                <span> No File</span>
                            </ng-template>

                               
                        </td>
```

in some cases `data.URL` is `null` `URL: "null"` and else there will be file url but in my component in all case View File is displayed.

another issue is I have url like this `https://egdomain/download_.jpg` i want to display only the file in the link not the full url like `download_.jpg`

Any solution to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `URL: "null"` is a string and not a `null` value. So along with null value, you also need to compare `"null"` string as well if you want to filter it out.

Something like below:

```
*ngIf="data?.URL && data.URL !== 'null'; else noData"
```

2. To play with the variables in view component in Angular, use `{{ ... }}` statements. Below is how you can trim the trailing `/` if present, split the whole string by `/` and get the last keyword (the file name) and display it:

```
<a [href]="...">{{data.URL.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/').pop()}}</a>
```

To optimize this solution, create a `pipe` to get the file name from URL, and append same above logic to that pipe and return the value.

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to change the href only want to manipulate name

Comment: Which name are you talking about? The link name is `View File` which is written between `<a>...</a>`

Comment: Yes the View File name <a> File name</a>

Comment: So instead of `View File`, you want to display the `download_.jpg` or whatever the file name in the `data.URL` ?

Comment: Yes only the filename

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token / i'm getting this error but previous solution was working this was working {{data?.attachmentURL.split('/').pop()}}, getting error at this line `{{data.URL.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/').pop()}}`

Comment: At what line? Can you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: You have to put `*ngIf` as I have mentioned. Then it will not throw any error.

Comment: error NG5002: Parser Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected character [\] at column 30 in expression [data?.URL.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/').pop()] at .. can you please check this, ngIf is there in anchor tag

Comment: `*ngIf` should be there on the same `<a>` tag, and in your question it is in same `<a>` tag.

Comment: I check this is working `{{data?.URL.split('/').pop()}}` is there any issue if i use this?

Comment: It will fail if there will be trailing `/` in the URL. If you are sure that there will never be any trailing `/` in the URL, then you can use your version.

Comment: I would recommend to create a pipe for this purpose and write the same code in pipe which I have provided. That would be more optimized and convenient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Understand this at first and then implement the same in your code.

**.Ts** file:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  nullVariable = null;

  isNameCheck(): boolean {
    if (typeof this.nullVariable != 'undefined' && this.nullVariable) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now to call the function in **.HTML** file:-
In this example, if `nullVariable` is empty or null, or undefined, It prints the empty message.

`nullVariable` can be a number or string or array or object.

```
<div *ngIf="nullVariable">
  <span>stringValue is not empty</span>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!nullVariable">
  <span>nullValue is empty.</span>
</div>
{{isNameCheck()}}
```

Comment: Using component methods directly in view are not recommended. They will slow down the DOM because of continuous method calls. Instead use `pipes` to perform any operations in view.